# Excel Worksheet with C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm updating a chart inside an excel in this way:

```
ChartObject Chart2 = (ChartObject)mWSheet1.ChartObjects(1);
Chart2.Activate();
Range chartRange2 = mWSheet3.UsedRange;
Chart2.Chart.SetSourceData(chartRange2, Missing.Value);
```

When I want to print the page `mWSheet1` only the chart is printed. How to get back the whole sheet to be printed?

Comment: copy sheet area as image and print that.

Comment: I'm using excel capailities for printing

Comment: Can you show your printing code?

Comment: As I said I'm using the Excel printing capabilities `mWSheet1.PrintPreview(false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either don't activate the chart in the first place, or activate the sheet it's on before printing:

```
Chart2.Parent.Parent.Cells(1).Activate
```